# How to Programmatically Compose Email using my mail account in Nokia Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia, qt-mobility

I am new to this concept. can you please just give some path to get solution, like which framework or library i need to use in my app for this work.

For example:

```
To:examples@example.com
subject: test mail
Message: body of the message
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Qt Mobility [Messaging API](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/messaging.html).

Answer (score 1):

Specific example with source code is [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-beta/writemessage.html)!!